# Does javascript controller differentiate between double or single quotes?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

My JS controller works completely fine when I replace single quotes with double quotes. Does it take both under consideration? Is it just a coincidence? Just wanted to confirm.

[image: I replaced single quotes with double]

Comment: It should work with single quotes too from Aura perspective. To understand more n single vs double quotes : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242813/when-should-i-use-double-or-single-quotes-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript has three types of strings, the single quote, double-quote, and backtick strings. This allows you to not have to always escape quotes:

```
let bobsBurger = "Bob's Burger";
let theSfdcFox = '"The Salesforce Fox"';
let welcome = `Hello, ${theSfdcFox}!`; // Hello, "The Salesforce Fox"!
```

The last form, called [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), allow you to evaluate expressions in the middle of the string with `${...}`, which is useful for avoiding the need for string concatenation.

Note that this is a feature of JavaScript itself, not Aura, so it also works in LWC, Visualforce, NodeJS scripts, etc.